# JList drag CustomObject but drop String

Tags: java, swing, jlist, drag-and-drop

```
private JList attributesList;

public AttributeGroupComponent(ArrayList<?> items) {
    attributesList = new JList(items.toArray());
    initGui();
}

private void initGui(){         
    attributesList.setDragEnabled(true);
}
```

then in other component I try

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
    Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();

    MyCustomClass ac = null;

    try {
        ac = (MyCustomClass)tr.getTransferData(flavor);
        // And Here I get toString of my custom class!
        // But I expected MyCustomClass Object!
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        ;// TODO
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ;// TODO
    }

    dtde.dropComplete(true);
    System.out.println("drop complete");
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Also, what flavor are you using?  A SSCCE would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to drag `MyCustomClass` from the JList to the drop component as the object itself, you would need to create a `Transferable` for that object.

Last year, I created something similar for all objects available in GitHub [easy-dnd-swing](https://github.com/mohamedmansour/easy-dnd-swing)

You would need to create your own DataFlavor that represents your object, then you setup your DragListeners and when you [startDrag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragSource.html#startDrag%28java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent,%20java.awt.Cursor,%20java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable,%20java.awt.dnd.DragSourceListener%29) with the custom Transferable that you create. That transferable will contain the object you will drag.